# Is it correct to say "There is more to success than hard work"?

Tags: phrases

There is a phrase:

> "*[...more to life than...](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/110187)*"

Is it possible to replace the word *life* in this phrase with something else?

Is it correct to say:

> "There is more to success than hard work"?

Comment: There is more to this question than meets the eye. Not.

Comment: It's syntactically correct.  Whether it's *true* is a separate discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. In general, *there is more to X than Y* just means that X does not only consist of Y but also other things.